# How can I use different loss functions for images with different labels in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two types of images, meaning two different sets of possible labels. How can I use two different loss functions based on which image I am currently training on with a batch size of 1?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, for 2 reasons:

1. It doesn't make mathematical sense. The Gradient must explore *one* loss function that is optimized to distinguish between *more than one* class. Using a loss function to classify a single class is equivalent to not learning anything.
2. In ML, the models you train are meant to generalize on data they have never seen before. Because of this, you can't use different loss functions because once you test its performance on test data nobody knows to what class they belong.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Maybe I wasn't clear in my question, but both images have more than one class, and are of almost the same object.

Comment: In that case, you can train one model for every class that each image can belong to. And for each Network you can choose the loss function you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

One option is [multi-task learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-task_learning). In this case, multi-task learning would allow a single model to learn more than one independent label for the same image. There is a separate loss function for each task (i.e., independent label). Those separate loss functions would be aggregated for a single loss function to train the overall model.

Training on a batch size of one will result in overfitting. The network will optimize for each image individually. Increasing batch will regularize, increasing generalization, across images.